# 413 Request Entity Too Large nginx/1.14.0

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, image-uploading

when i upload the image from localhost i can upload the image of any size but when i try to upload through the server it gives me the error of request entity too large when the image size greater then 1Mb i have added this client_max_body_size 100M; and restart the nginx but still issue is here somebody knows what going wrong /var/www/abc/abc/nginx.config path is here?

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript 
text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
client_max_body_size 100M;
}




<html>
<head>
    <title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
    <center>
        <h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried `upload_max_filesize = 100M`, `post_max_size = 100M`?

Comment: Apparently you have edited wrong file (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) or the format is not correct. Please post the full config file and mention its path in your question.

Comment: nope i don't try this

Comment: Xaqron how i edited wrong file ?

Comment: If you are not `symlinking` configuration files from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled` or in config file for example by not putting the config key/val in the right block (i.e. `server`).

Comment: Xaqron not please check my path and code in config file

Comment: The HTML code should not be there ([sample](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/)). Also if you don't mind changing upload limit for all sites change the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. That's the shortest way to address the issue in a comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197534/discussion-between-hammad-ul-hasan-and-xaqron).

Answer (score 1):

everything was fine just to wrong path of ngnix.conf there was the error so please be sure when you adding this line in the nginx.conf be sure you ngnix.conf is at right path